# tool for retrieving the list of functions and methods in a C++ code base

Tags: c++, list, methods

Considering a C++ based source code i'm looking for a tool that can output a plain text list of methods with/without interfaces, this means 2 options, only the method's name or the complete interface's signature.

I would like to apply this to source code in C too.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe a bit overkill, but have you looked at doxygen?

Comment: @paddy if the output isn't in plain text there is no point about using a tool for having a dirty output that i'm supposed to clean with the same regex rules that i'm supposed to use for the original code base; it's like going in circle for nothing.

Comment: I merely posed the question of whether you'd looked at it, presuming that doxygen might have an option for plaintext output.  Anyway, regex rules for processing marked-up text are much easier than those for parsing C code.  So you can't really call that a circle.

Comment: @Ken, a regex to parse e.g. the output of [ctags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags) would be an order of magnitude easier than a complete C++ parser to extract member function declarators from arbitrarily complex C++ source code. Dismissing a partial solution because it needs a little bit more effort is pretty shortsighted.

Comment: @JonathanWakely show your example using ctags

Comment: `ctags -x  --extra=q foo.cc  | awk '$1 ~ "::" { print $1 }'` ... now you show how to do that "with the same regex rules [...] for the original code base"

Comment: btw, how do you plan to extract "methods" from C code?  Do you mean functions?  In that case it's even easier: ctags -x --extra=q foo.cc | awk '$2 == "function" { print $1 }'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A reasonable solution cam be built easily using Doxygen's XML format and a little python script to parse it. Doxygens XML output is not very well documented, but seems pretty complete.

Here's my python script:

```
import lxml.etree
import glob

prefix = "/Code/stack_overflow_examples/list_functions_by_doxygen/"

for filename in glob.glob("xml/*.xml"):
    f = open( filename, "r" )
    xml = lxml.etree.parse(f)
    for x in xml.xpath('//memberdef[@kind="function"]'):
        srcfile = x.xpath('.//location/@file')[0].replace(prefix,'') 
        srcline = x.xpath('.//location/@line')[0]
        definition = x.xpath('.//definition/text()')[0] 
        args = x.xpath('.//argsstring/text()')[0]
        print( "%s:%s: %s%s" % ( srcfile, srcline, definition, args) )
```

When run on this file:

```
/**
 * This is a test function.
 */
int a_function( Baz & b )
{
  return 7;
}

void another_function( Boo & b )
{
}

class Foo
{
  private:
    int a_private_member_function();
  public:
    int a_public_member_function();
};
```

It generates this output:

```
test.cpp:16: int Foo::a_private_member_function()
test.cpp:18: int Foo::a_public_member_function()
test.cpp:5: int a_function(Baz &b)
test.cpp:10: void another_function(Boo &b)
```

You'll just need to make a couple of changes to the Doxyfile you use to generate the "docs".
Here's the changes I used:

```
EXTRACT_ALL = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS = YES
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES = YES
CASE_SENSE_NAMES = YES

GENERATE_HTML = NO
GENERATE_LATEX = NO
GENERATE_XML = YES
```

Answer (score 7):

According to Jonathan Wakely's comment you can use [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/ctags.html) like that:

```
ctags -x --c-types=f --format=1 file.c
```

It would list your functions:

```
celsjusz2Fahrenheit   17 file.c double celsjusz2Fahrenheit(double celsjuszDegree)
celsjusz2Kelwin    21 file.c double celsjusz2Kelwin(double celsjuszDegree)
main               44 file.c int main()
```

If you want to list methods proceded by class name, You can use:

```
ctags -x --c++-types=f --extra=q --format=1 file.cc
```

it will print e.g:

```
S::f                9 file.cc void f()
S::f1              11 file.cc void f1()
S::f2              13 file.cc void f2()
celsjusz2Fahrenheit   17 file.cc double celsjusz2Fahrenheit(double celsjuszDegree)
celsjusz2Kelwin    21 file.cc double celsjusz2Kelwin(double celsjuszDegree)
```

EDIT (because of comments): Args means (copied from `ctags --help`):

- `-x` - Print a tabular cross reference file to standard output.
- `--extra=q` - adds extra flag, where `q` means "Include an extra class-qualified tag entry for each tag"
- `--format=1` - Force output of specified tag file format

Comment: Good solution :)

Comment: Could be more helpful if some explanations are provided. As I put these commands on macOS, the output is simply "illegal option".